# How can i make a Binary Tree from text file in Python

Tags: python, binary-tree

So I started working on this project for school and im new to python and am not sure how to complete it or if im going about it the best way and dont have anyone to ask about it. Basically what i want to do is create a list from the text file, make it into a binary tree and end up with an output like in a pyramid
1
2 3
X 4 X 10
(X appears when there isnt a child)
I was given some skeleton code for the classes i need and This is what i got so far just trying to think though it but im not sure where to go. (I'm already submitting my work and wont be using the code for class but still want to see if someone could help get it to work just so i can understand it)

```
with open('treenums.txt') as f:
  my_list = [ int(i) for i in f ]

class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None
        self.parent= None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.root = None

    def insertNode(self,value):
        if self.root==None:
            self.root=Node(value)
        else:
            self.insertNode(self.root)

        if value < self.root.value:
            if self.root.left_child==None:
                self.root.left_child=Node(value)
                self.root.left_child.parent=self.root
            else:
                self.insertNode(self.root.left_child)
        elif value > self.root.value:
            if self.root.right_child==None:
                self.root.right_child=Node(value)
                self.root.right_child.parent=self.root
            else:
                self.insertNode(self.root.right_child)
        return

    def printTree(self):
        if self.root!=None:
            self._print_tree(self.root.left_child)
            print (str(self.root.value))
            self._print_tree(self.root.right_child)
        return

my_tree = Tree() 
for item in [5, 7, 8]:
    my_tree.insertNode(item)

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

node_a = Node(3)
node_b = Node(5)
node_c = Node(7)

node_a.left_child = node_b
node_b.right_child = node_c

root=node_a
current_node = root

if (42 == current_node.value):
    print('found')
elif 42 < current_node.value:
    current_node = current_node.left_child
else:
    current_node = current_node.right_child

print(node_a)
print(node_b)
print(node_a.value, node_a.left_child, node_a.right_child)
print(node_a.left_child.right_child)
```

Comment: Welcome! We need more clarification on "make it into a binary tree and end up with an output like in a **pyramid 1 2 3 X 4 X 10 (X appears when there isnt a child)**" That doesn't look like a pyramid. You might need to copy the pyramid text into a code block.

Comment: It also looks like you're not just wanting to create any Binary Tree, but a Binary Search Tree (BST) (there's a difference). A binary tree is one whose nodes have at most two children. A BST is a binary tree, s.t. each node satisfy the condition `node.left_child.val < node.val < node.right_child.val` (I'm also assuming the tree has no duplicate values).

Comment: Oh shoot, I didnt know there was a difference.  No duplicate values, its just 5 numbers to start. Not a BST.

Comment: Your `insertNode` method strongly suggests it's a BST.